# Datatable becomes null when first datatable becomes null

Tags: c#

I am working on c# application where I have to compare two tables and any differences will be stored in 3rd datatable. I used following code

```
Dttag.rows.clear();
Dttag = Getdata();

if (dtBuffer == null)
{
    dtBuffer = Dttag;
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Dttag.rows.count; i++)
    {
        if (dt.rows[0][0] != dtBuffer.rows[0][0])
        {
            Dtresult.rows.add(dt.rows[0][0]);
        }
    }

    dtBuffer = Dttag;
}
```

Here when the Dttag becomes null dtBuffer also becomes null. But I want dtBuffer not to get null. How to do this?

Comment: If this really C#? It does not compile.

Comment: What about checking if _Dttag_ is null after you call the GetData method? If null, return immediately or exclude the execution of the block with the for loop

Comment: All code is inside loop which runs for 50 times. When it enters inside loop Dttag has to be null every time.  It is surely c #

Comment: Then it seems some important context is missing from your code. And `If` `Else` etc. is not how these keywords are written in C#.

Comment: You need to be **aware** that C# is **case-sensitive** - so you need to use `if`, `else`, `for` - not `If`, `Else`, `For` ....

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be sure without more context, but the issue likely stems from this line:

```cs
dtBuffer=Dttag;
```

In C# this is most likely causing `dtBuffer` to be a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). Odds are that in this situation you need to use `dtBuffer` before it is being disposed of.